# how to use barer token in register api flutter

Tags: post, flutter

i am having an url related to generate the access token for registration and i am getting the response.but my problem is i am unable to use the generated token in register api as header.can any one help me solve this issues

```
Future<Map> ajaxPost (Register regData) async {
```

var response = await http.post(
        'your api client_credentials',
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Basic barer token"},
      );

```
    responseBody = json.decode(response.body);

    print(responseBody);                 
return responseBody;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is it that does not work? Do you put "Bearer " before the token? What if you try the following example?

```
 Map<String, String> headers = {
  HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: "Bearer $token",
  HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json",
  "Accept": "application/json"
};

await client.post(url, body: json.encode(body), headers: headers);
```

Comment: i want to use the barer token for enter application.can i save the token in shared preferences?

Comment: Of course. Something like: preferences.setString('token', token). See [link](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) 

The above answer was to use it in a http post. If you get the token from the response, you can save it in Shared prefs.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean? If you want to register users in the app, you can't use a token yet. Token is generated when a user is registered/logged in.

What you could do is make an Authorization key for register and login. When logged in you'll have your token, save it to prefs and token can be used for all all user/account related things .

Comment: My problem was in the given apis they are passing the barer token in headers in all apis ,so by using the token api i am getting the tokens and i was save the response token in shared preference .now how to use the saved token in the headers of all the apis